# Checking if one combobox is empty and the other one isn't

Tags: excel, vba

I have two combo boxes, one to select month and one to select year.

What I want to do is not allow users to select only month or only year, they have to select both.

I have tried to do the following

```
If UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value = Null And UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value <> Null Then
MsgBox "Please select a year"

End If

If UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value = Null And UserForm.ComboBox5.Value <> Null Then

MsgBox "Please select a month"

End If
```

This gives me an error because in both cases for one of the combo boxes nothing has been selected at all so by doing .Value then it breaks as there is no value.

How can I fix this so it asks if nothing has been selected in one of the combo boxes?

Comment: `And UserForm.ComboBox5.Value <> Null Then` should probably be `And UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value <> Null Then` You missed a "1" in the userform name. If you are running this from the userform you can use `Me.ComboBox5` instead.

Comment: That's for the error. To get it to actually work, you might want ot change `Null` to `""`

Comment: `If ComboBox5.Listindex= -1 And ComboBox6.Listindex= -1 Then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ListIndex`

**Example 1**

Handling it together.

```
If ComboBox5.ListIndex = -1 Or ComboBox6.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Select both Year and Month"
Else
    '
    ' ~~> Do what you want
    '
End If
```

**Example 2**

Handling it separately

```
If ComboBox5.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Select Year"
    Exit Sub
End If

If ComboBox6.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Select Month"
    Exit Sub
End If

'
'~~> Do what you want
'
```

**Note**

If you want to use `.Value` then use it like this

```
If Len(Trim(ComboBox5.Value)) = 0 Then

End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the ListIndex approach and it worked perefectly!

Comment: It should be `Or` in the first example.

Comment: @BrakNicku: Yes you are right. Updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the changing to both ComboBox and use empty string instead of `null`

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
   If UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value = "" And UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value <> "" Then
      MsgBox "Please select a year"
   End If
   If UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value = "" And UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value <> "" Then
      MsgBox "Please select a month"
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox6_Change()
   If UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value = "" And UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value <> "" Then
      MsgBox "Please select a year"
   End If
   If UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value = "" And UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value <> "" Then
      MsgBox "Please select a month"
   End If
End Sub
```